# Synchronizing Outlook Calendar Categories with a Sharepoint calendar using email address assigned to SP calendar

Tags: 2013, calendar, outlook, categories

I have a SharePoint calendar configured with an incoming email and want to populate events with categories in the SharePoint calendar by sending events from Outlook to SharePoint. I have the same categories in Outlook and in the SharePoint calendar.

When I enter in Outlook an event with a category directly in the SharePoint calendar connected to Outlook, then the category is correctly updated in the calendar on SharePoint.
However, when I create an event with the same category in Outlook using my Outlook Exchange Account and send the event to the SharePoint calendar's incoming email address, then the event in SharePoint does not contain the category.

Has anyone been able to get this to work or has suggestions for workarounds using the incoming email feature?

We are using Outlook 2013 and Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case, the issue is that there was many "category" columns on Sharepoint, but only in the **Site Column** called "Categories", configured as type: Single line of text, could be updated directly from an event created on Outlook.
Site Column options is located at: (Sharepoint Site): Site Settings\Galleries\Site Columns.

This case refers to the use of:
- Outlook 2013.
- Sharepoint 2010.